# Alterar conta github no VsCode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Como eu faço para alterar a conta padrão do GitHub dentro do VS Code, pois quando vou criar um repositório remoto (Botão: Publish to GitHub) sempre aponta para a conta errada!

Hoje no VsCode está configurada a conta AtilaLavor mas gostaria de configurar outra!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Eu tive o mesmo problema tempos atrás, tenta rodar isso:

`git config --global user.email "email@example.com"`

Encontrei também a seguinte maneira de alterar a conta padrão (que não era meu caso):

> Geralmente o VSCode usa as credenciais do github do gerenciador de credenciais do sistema, ele não armazena em qualquer lugar nas configurações.
> Então experimente pesquisar ou ir até o gerenciador de credenciais (painel de controle do Windows) -> Credenciais do Windows -> Atualize a senha do GitHub na lista.

Espero ter ajudado!